# How to type a wrapper function for emotion's styled function properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, emotion

I am using `styled-system` with `emotion` and I am writing a wrapper function to abstract away some of the details I necessarily care about for most components. The wrapper function already works, but I would like to add TypeScript types to it.

You can check out the files on Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-water-85v0z

```
// styledSystemComponent.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { styled } from '../styles/theme';
import { color, space, layout, flexbox } from 'styled-system';
import shouldForwardProp from '@styled-system/should-forward-prop';

// TODO: Type this function properly
function styledSystemComponent<Tag extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements, ExtraProps = {}>(
  tag: Tag,
  styleObject?: StyledOptions
);
function styledSystemComponent<Tag extends React.ComponentType<any>, ExtraProps = {}>(
  tag: Tag,
  styleObject?: StyledOptions
) {
  return styled(tag)(
    {
      ...styleObject,
      shouldForwardProp,
    },
    color,
    space,
    layout,
    flexbox
  );
}
```

```
// Box.tsx
import { styledSystemComponent } from '../../utils/styledSystemComponent';

const Box = styledSystemComponent('div', {
  // styles go here
});
```

I tried copying the types from Emotion's `styled` function, but I can't get the return type of `styledSystemComponent` quite right.

[image: the type is React.ComponentType<any>]

This is what you get when you 'go to definition' on `emotion`'s `styled` function.

[image: emotion styled function definition type interface]

This is what I came up with:

```
function styledSystemComponent<Tag extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements, ExtraProps = {}>(
  tag: Tag,
  styleObject?: StyledOptions
);
function styledSystemComponent<Tag extends React.ComponentType<any>, ExtraProps = {}>(
  tag: Tag,
  styleObject?: StyledOptions
) {
  return styled(tag)(
    {
      ...styleObject,
      shouldForwardProp,
    },
    color,
    space,
    layout,
    flexbox
  );
}
```

It works, but I'm still missing the return types. When I mouse hover over `Box` it says the type is `any`.

My TypeScript knowledge isn't advanced enough to solve this problem. I feel like I'm not understanding something but I cannot tell what I'm missing here. I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: I think I could help how Mui solved this https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-styled-engine/src/index.js